# Disable WordPress Redirect From terminal

Tags: configuration, redirect

I am in the process of transferring a WordPress server from the IP address "12.34.45.67" to a new server "11.11.11.11".

Unfortunately, I set the WordPress address and the site address
as seen here in [this screenshot](https://codex.wordpress.org/File:options-general.png) to the first IP address 12.34.45.67.

I have now moved the site, and when I attempt the access the homepage from 11.11.11.11, I am redirected to 12.34.45.67.

I am currently trying to use in my `wp-config.php` file and adding the following lines: (code from wp docs [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php))

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://11.11.11.11');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://11.11.11.11');
```

No success; however, the redirect is now only limited to `11.11.11.11`,
entering the url `11.11.11.11/wp-admin` results in a 500 error code

Comment: changed both ip addresses to 11.11.11.11,

Answer (score 1):

### Use Development Address Not Root IP.

You are using a root IP. You need to direct to your site to the correct dev location. Something like this: `https://74.104.158.116/~lbryhub`.

### Viewing your URL From [WHM](https://cpanel.com/products/#whm) (if you use it?)

I find working on a subdomain easier such as https://new.exmaple.com, then I migrate it over to the correct domain when finished: https://exmaple.com

[image]

### Creating Development Subdomains in [cPanel](https://cpanel.com/products/#cpanel) (if you use it?)

[image]

Comment: should i change my code in wp-config.php to:
define('WP_HOME', 'http://11.11.11.11/~lbryred/');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://11.11.11.11/~lbryred/');

Comment: No. You have to find the dev URL on your server and change to that. Are you self-hosting or with a hosting provider?

Comment: I am hosting on Digitalocean I just transferred my work as a screenshot

Comment: If you send Digital Ocean a support message, they will be able to tell you what your dev URL is. If you have WHM, you can find it in there. Each hosting provider has a diffrent set up. If you have a domain name on there, you can add a sub domain to it and map it to that while developing.

Comment: The dev URL will most likly be <your ip>/~<username> Example: http://11.11.11.11/~mysite

Comment: https://www.lockedownseo.com/install-wordpress-without-domain-name/

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?